# How to create a background method which waits for an input signal? (beginner java)

Tags: java, eclipse, sockets

I am currently programming a socket video player program with server/client. Please note, I am extremely new to Java (eclipse)

I have managed to get both to connect to each other. First the server sends it's list of video names, then the client clicks the (Jbox) and sends back the corresponding video selected. The server then streams the video across to the client player.

The only problem I have now is that making a method(?) run in the background of the main code while the video is running which waits for a different video select signal. How would I go about doing this without pausing the main code? I realize the main code and the wait for signal code must run simultaneously . I am looking for someone to redirect me to a simple guide with examples.

Thank you

Comment: Its nice concept.. How are you streaming video?

Comment: You'll need to do some research into threading and locks

Answer (score 0):

One possible way would be to use threads. The server will use a thread (may be the main thread) to send the list of videos and when the request is received by the server, it starts a thread to send the video stream to the client in a separate thread.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

Create a `CallbackObject` that stores what you need for a callback function e.g. a message:

```
public class CallbackObject {

    /* Any members you need for the callback object .. */
    private String message;

    public CallbackObject(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    /*
     * Call this function when the thread has finished e.g.
     * finished waiting, processing, etc. You could also just
     * set a flag for the main thread here.
     */
    public void callbackFunction() {
        System.out.println("CALLBACK MESSAGE: \"" + this.message + "\"");           
    }

    /* 
     * Allows you to modify your shared data. This is where you could
     * also set e.g. a selected video, ready for the main thread to 
     * pick up. Note that 'synchronized' ensures that only one thread
     * at a time can modify 'this.message'. 
     */
    public void clearMessage(String newMessage) { 
        synchronized(this.message) {
            this.message = newMessage;
        }
    }

    /*
     * Get the shared data.
     */
    public String getMessage() {
        return this.message;
    }       
}
```

You can pass this callback object to a thread e.g. `WorkerThread` that waits, processes or does whatever you want but uses `CallbackObject` in order to change or process data:

```
public class WorkerThread extends Thread {

    /* Our callback object */
    private CallbackObject callbackObject;

    public WorkerThread (CallbackObject callbackObject) {
        this.callbackObject = callbackObject;
    }

    /*
     * Main function of the thread.
     */
    public void run() {

        System.out.println("Hello from WorkerThread!");

        try {
            // THIS THREAD SLEEPS FOR ONE SECOND
            Thread.sleep(1000);

           // In YOUR program you wait for input or do whatever here

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        callbackObject.callbackFunction();          
        callbackObject.clearMessage("<empty message>");

        System.out.println("CallbackThread done.");
    }
}
```

You could use it like that:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    CallbackObject callbackObject = new CallbackObject("Callback object message!");
    WorkerThread workerThread = new WorkerThread(callbackObject);

    workerThread.start();

    String exitCmd = new String();

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    // ENTER 'exit' TO STOP THE PROGRAM

    while(exitCmd.equals("exit") == false) {
        exitCmd = in.nextLine();
    }

    in.close();

    System.out.println("CallbackObject (empty) message: " + callbackObject.getMessage());
    System.out.println("Exiting ..");
}
```

As you can see you can also see the changes made to `message` on the main thread after your callback thread exited.